# Confusion about html structure

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I'm working with a **bootstrap code** and trying to find out how it works. In the main html code, there is a part for the sidebar. When I remove this part the sidebar gets removed. But none of the parts of the sidebar are in the code.

Where are the different parts of sidebar defined?

Following is the **code** for sidebar

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left active"
            style="height: calc(100vh - 50px - 1px - 20px);">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="menu"                                          role="navigation"
                style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100%;">
                <div id="tabs" role="tabpanel">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the sidebar is removed or just not being displayed anymore? You should post a bit more code...

Comment: a quick guess: put some list items <li> in the <ul>-node. And some content in the div-node with the class "tab-content" and see what happens.